# android Accelerometer on X-Axis

Tags: java, android, mobile, accelerometer

I think this is a simple question for you guys (it's just I'm new in this business):
so, In my android java-based game I have this ball, and..
I want to detect the user movement.
if the user tilt the device to the right, the ball will roll to the right side
if the user tilt the device to the left, the ball will roll to the left side.

so, in short:
how to "connect" the ball to the device-movement (only on x-axis - right & left)

thanks,
sock.socket

Comment: please post what you have tried.

Comment: what you are searching for, is the gyroscope. check google and or stackoverflow... you´ll find tons of examples.

Comment: I didnt try much.. because I got a lack of information about it.  
what I need is to detect the direction of the device and my character
should accelerate to the left/right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare your Sensor and sensor manager

```
public Sensor mySensor;
private SensorManager mySensorManager;
```

Then initialize the variables to your liking. I chose to have my sensor delay as normal and my accuracy sensitivity to high.

```
mySensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
mySensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
mySensorManager.registerListener(this, mySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH);
```

Now you will need an onSensorChanged function that will run every time your sensor senses a change. Within this function, you can animate your ball.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    x = event.values[0];

    // The x value in the accelerometer is the 0th index in the array

    // Now you may do what you wish with this x value, and use it to move your ball 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't find SENSOR_SERVICE

Comment: I haven't written Android in a while, but I think SENSOR_SERVICE was automatically imported in Android Studio. You have to import SENSOR_SERVICE because it is a constant from the Android API. Otherwise, the IDE is going to think it's a local variable and won't find it.